# ROS Answers SE migration: Rosserial help

Tags: ros, arduino, c++, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
I am a beginner in ROS and have been confused very lately on how to set this up. I have 3 nodes in my current ROS setup.
I want Arduino to be the 4th node and fetch/send values from these 3 nodes. But the code we upload in Arduino is .ino format ? I know there's a rosserial package in existence, but I can't figure out how to actually make it a node(which requires a cpp or py format I think).

Rosserial site says :
"It allows your Arduino to be a full fledged ROS node which can directly publish and subscribe to ROS messages, publish TF transforms, and get the ROS system time."

Does that mean I simply publish and subscribe in my ino file (which need not be in my catkin_ws folder) and just upload it to arduino and run roscore+other nodes ?

Please clear the confusion! Thanks :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238058/rosserial-help/) by [silverbullet](https://answers.ros.org/users/27197/silverbullet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-06-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [silverbullet](https://answers.ros.org/users/27197/silverbullet/) on 2016-06-29**:
Bump. Anyone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, I believe `rosserial` is the right answer. Check out the tutorials (http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial/Tutorials) and this introductory video / presentation from ROSCon 2014: https://vimeo.com/106992629

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2016-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [silverbullet](https://answers.ros.org/users/27197/silverbullet/) on 2016-06-26**:
Hi! I've already seen the tutorials but they aren't so clear. Can you answer my questions bit more specifically? Thanks :)